# I cannot use the remove(int) method, symbol not found error

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, compiler-errors

I'm trying to make a method, `removeAnObject`, that removes an object from an array and returns a boolean value, but I'm running across a weird `symbol not found` error when trying to use the remove method from the Arraylist class.

Here is method:

```
 public boolean removeAnObject(Element anObject)
      {
         int whereWeAre;
         String paramClass;
         String currClass;
         boolean weFoundIt;

         paramClass = anObject.getClassName();
         whereWeAre = 0;
         weFoundIt = false;


         while(whereWeAre != currentSize && weFoundIt == false)
         {
            currClass = theList[whereWeAre].getClassName();
            if(currClass.equals(paramClass))
            {
               theList.remove(whereWeAre);
               weFoundIt = true;
            }

            else
            {
               whereWeAre++;
            }

         }

         return weFoundIt;

      }
```

Here is the error:

```
ElementSet.java:262: error: cannot find symbol
               theList.remove(theList[whereWeAre]);
                      ^
  symbol:   method remove(Element)
  location: variable theList of type Element[]
1 error
```

Final note: I do have the `import java.util.ArrayList` at the beginning of the class.

Comment: You can't call the `remove` method on an array -- only `Object` methods.

Comment: Arrays don't have a remove method. An ArrayList is an implementation of a List which is backed by an array. I think you might be confusing the terms /ideas...

Comment: If your declaration of `theList` is `Element[] theList`, then it's a regular array, not an `ArrayList`.  You have to say that it's an `ArrayList`: `ArrayList<Element> theList`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return true` instead of `return weFoundIt` ? Since it's already a `public boolean` method.

Comment: @Xbit Why would he want to return `true` if `weFoundIt` is `false`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you use an array , you replace:

```
theList.remove(whereWeAre);
```

with

```
theList[whereWeAre] = null;
```

This line will make the place `whereWeAre` empty thus removing the searched `Element`.

Don't forget to add a null checking condition if you intent to reuse your method multiple time on the same array. Otherwise, you'll face a `NullPointerException`.

```
     while(whereWeAre != currentSize && weFoundIt == false)
     {
        if (theList[whereWeAre]!=null)
        {
            currClass = theList[whereWeAre].getClassName();
            if(currClass.equals(paramClass))
            {
               theList.remove(whereWeAre);
               weFoundIt = true;
            }
            else
            {
               whereWeAre++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            whereWeAre++;
        }
     }
```

Comment: @user3150298 THIS MAY NOT BE WHAT YOU WANT.  This solution would change the whole design of what `removeAnObject` does.  The effect would be to leave an array with holes in it, and the array would be the same size as before.  If `theList` were an `ArrayList` and you used `remove`, that would actually remove the element and shorten the array, and the elements above the removed one would shift down and would now be at different indexes.  You must be aware of the difference and make a decision about what you want the effect to be.

Comment: I am downvoting this answer because, after looking at it more closely, it will **fail**.  The original code does not increment `whereWeAre` if it removes the element, which would be correct if this were an `ArrayList` and it actually squeezed the element out.  But if this is the only change that's made, what will happen is that `theList[whereWeAre]` will be set to null, `whereWeAre` will not get  incremented, the program will loop back and then `theList[whereWeAre].getClassName()` will throw an NPE.

Comment: @ajb The program will leave the loop because `weFoundIt` is true. That's right that if the method is called multiple time on the same array, it must be changed for null checking.

Comment: sorry, I missed that--I thought he was removing every occurrence of the object.

Comment: @ajb Anyway, your *downvoting* reveals a bug in case of multiple use of the same method on the same array :p. But OP didn't give us his context... homework or code for production ?

Answer (score 1):

The method remove(parameter) with an int as parameter for ArrayList also has a return of type E, being the Object of Object type  specified when creating the list.

So for starters when you are using theList[] I'm assuming it's an array of ArrayLists()
and that you are sure theList is of type ArrayList and not an Array.

1- Save and recompile your code, the error line is nowhere in the code you specified.
2- Make sure theList[whereWeAre] is an int if you're using the above specified method.

3- Why not just use this method included in ArrayList() class:

```
public boolean remove(Object o)
```

which will remove the first occurence of the object and return true if successful.
Learn more here: [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: Ahh right that would be easier to use, thank you for this information.